# How to build Angular 4 app using visual studio 2017 build command?

Tags: angular, visual-studio, angular-cli

In my solution, I have a Web API & an Angular4 project. I have created the angular project using Angular CLI. I want the Angular4 project to be built when I use Ctrl+Shift+B (Build Solution) command in Visual Studio 2017. Is there a way to do this? I currently open command prompt & navigate to the folder & type 
    ng build

Comment: Maybe try this? https://angular.io/guide/visual-studio-2015#build-and-run

Comment: Thanks @PeterKim for your help. However, I want to build the app i.e. create a dist folder with typescript transpiled in it & not run the app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49238630/how-to-use-angular-cli-with-visual-studio-2017-without-build-errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set pre-build and post-build events in your project so you can run your command from there.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-specify-build-events-csharp?view=vs-2017